# nav_msgs::Path’ has no member named ‘set_poses_size’?

Tags: ros, nav-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a package that compiles successfully in diamondback. When I compile it in fuerte, it fails and indicates that "error: ‘nav_msgs::Path’ has no member named ‘set_poses_size’". What is wrong with fuerte? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63815/nav_msgs::path%E2%80%99-has-no-member-named-%E2%80%98set_poses_size%E2%80%99-???/) by [tony](https://answers.ros.org/users/2149/tony/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2013-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This function was deprecated some time ago. You should instead use poses.resize() as poses is a std::vector. See item #10 on the [migration guide](http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Migration#error:_XXX_has_no_member_named_.27set_YYY_size.27_.28or_.27get_YYY_size.27.29)

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4